# OpenStreetMap modify tags based on multiple criteria

Tags: openstreetmap, osmfilter

I have and .osm file and I would like the modify the tags based on the following criteria.

- If highway = "unclassified"
- and has a cycleway tag
- Then change highway to "tertiary"

I know that with [osmfilter](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter#Tags_Modification) I can modify all the "unclassified" roads

```
./osmfilter streets.osm --modify-tags="highway=unclassifiedto =tertiary" -o=streets2.osm
```

But is there a way to specify the additional criteria? Preferably a method that works on large osm files.

Comment: Maybe check out pyosmium, which is much more flexible: https://github.com/osmcode/pyosmium/blob/master/examples/normalize_boolean.py

Answer (score 1):

If it's a one-off and the file is small enough to be loaded in [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/), one of the more popular OSM editing tools, this might be the easiest option. Use JOSM's search function (Edit > Search, or Ctrl+F) to select the correct features and edit them all at once. In your example, the search query would be `highway=unclassified cycleway=*`.

For large files, and as long as a bit of programming is acceptable, you could use one of the various libraries for reading and writing OSM files (such as [osmium](https://osmcode.org/libosmium/), [pyosmium](https://osmcode.org/pyosmium/), [osm4j](https://jaryard.com/projects/osm4j/), ...) to write a small script in your language of choice.

(As an aside, you may want to handle cycleway=no differently from other cycleway tags.)